# How to find the Youtube Channels by location using youtube api

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to find youtube channels by country

```
req = youtube.search().list(location='37.42307,-122.08427', part='snippet', type='channel',locationRadius='10mi')
res = req.execute()
```

But I'm getting this error

> returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details:
> "[{'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'domain':
> 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}]">